# Trying to show that a set of data (speed at t=x) follows exponential decay given that dV/dt ∝ V

Tags: integration, differential-equations

So I have a set of data points with time and RPM.This came from an experiment involving a wheel mounted to a motor and the motor is slowed down using eddy current braking.

In this experiment, it is known that `dV/dt ∝ V`, so I assume `dV/dT = -kV` ,where k is assumed to be an unknown constant.

By solving this I get      V=e<sup>-kt</sup>

However when I plot the data points in excel and create a trend line the equation comes out as V=a*e<sup>-kt</sup>

Iv tried working backwards from this to figure our where the co-efficient `a` came from however it seems like I have to make up a constant of `1/a` in the integration of `1/V` in order for me to get V=a*e<sup>-kt</sup> as the mathematical line of best fit.

Apart from these attempts I'm clueless as to how I go from `dV/dt ∝ V`to V=a*e<sup>-kt</sup>

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: @WrichikBasu That comment is useless to a new user without linking to an explanation of what MathJax is, such as [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please try to write comments that *actually help a clueless user to figure out what could be improved about their posts*.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to see this.

## Direct integration

The expression $$\frac{dV}{dt} = -k~V$$
is of the form $$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{g(t)}{f(V(t))},$$ and can be solved by direct integration, $$\int dt~f(V)~\frac{dV}{dt} = \int g(t)~dt = G(t) + C.$$ Note that the left-hand side admits a $u$-substitution for $u=V, du=\frac{dV}{dt}~dt,$ so this becomes $$\int du~f(u) = G(t) + C.$$One does not need a separate constant of integration for the left-hand side as both appear in the same place, so one can instead just calculate the antiderivative $F$ and invert it to get $$V = F^{-1}(G(t) + C).$$ Of course in your case $g(t) = -k$ and therefore $G(t) = -k~t.$

For the special case $f(u) = 1/u$ that you have, the antiderivative is $F(u) =\ln |u|$ and hence the general solution is $$V = \pm\exp(-k t + C) = C'~e^{-kt},$$ where $C' = \pm e^{C}$ relates these two ways of showing the constant of integration.

More practice: in air, large things usually obey quadratic drag, meaning that Newton's laws for a skydiver will have the form $m~\frac{dv}{dt} = m~g-k~v^2.$ Work out what $v(t)$ is.

## Linearity conditions

More particular to the form you have, your equation is a *homogeneous* equation containing a *linear differential operator*, which is a complicated way to say that if you find two solutions $V_{1,2}$ of this equation, the new solution $V_3(t) = \alpha V_1(t) + \beta V_2(t)$ also solves this equation. This is a more direct way to see why this prefactor *must* be necessary for a wide range of different phenomena.

More practice: the linearly damped harmonic oscillator is $\ddot x =-\omega^2~ x -2\lambda~\dot x.$ Show that for $\lambda < \omega$ there are solutions of the form $e^{-\lambda~t}\cos(\alpha t)$ and $e^{-\lambda t}\sin(\alpha t).$ I will also tell you that this equation gives us the full trajectory from only knowing $x(0)$ and $\dot x(0),$ prove that this implies that this "linear superposition" solution $x(t) = e^{-\lambda t}(A \sin(\alpha t) + B\cos(\alpha t))$ for undetermined $A, B$ is the most general possible solution.

Comment: So it seems like I definitely lack knowledge and experience when solving for solutions like this. When solving using what I know by adding the C I got a solution with C in the power of e and I failed to see this connection that it could be taken out as a constant. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Uniqx well that's what learning is for; I didn't get this all the first time either. Heck if you want something really embarrassing, in the first year of my Master's degree I emailed a professor to warn him that his problem contained something like $y^2 + y \sqrt{1-y} + \dots_1 = \dots_2$ which is unsolvable because of the square root. He actually took time to patiently reply, explaining "you move the $y^2+\dots_1$ to the other side and square both sides and now it's just a quartic polynomial in $y$ and we can see two of the roots immediately so we can factor those out..." -- I was mortified.